# MSBuild condition to prevent app.config XML transform

Tags: xml, msbuild, slowcheetah, xdt-transform

I am using the 'SlowCheetah' VS extension to transform our app.config with different values depending on the project configuration. So a 'Debug' configuration produces an app.config with values appropriate for Dev/Qa users, while a 'Release' build produces an app.config with production values.

The .csproj contains a section like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
<None Include="App.config">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
</None>
<None Include="App.Debug.config">
  <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
  <IsTransformFile>True</IsTransformFile>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</None>    
<None Include="App.Release.config">
  <DependentUpon>App.config</DependentUpon>
  <IsTransformFile >True</IsTransformFile>    
</None>
<None Include="packages.config" />
<None Include="Properties\SlowCheetah\SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets" />
```

And the msbuild logic is contained mostly in the 'SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets' file. My files are being transformed correctly.

I want to protect against a developer accidentally running a 'Release' build inside Visual Studio and inadvertently running my app with a production config file. My idea is to use an msbuild condition, possibly something like:

```
Condition=" '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'=='true' "
```

I've tried using this condition in several places in the .csproj file without success. I suspect I could get this to work if I modify the 'SlowCheetah.Transforms.targets' file itself, but that file should not be modified according to the comments at the top.

Ideally I would like ALL configurations for builds inside Visual Studio to use my Debug config file, and 'Release' builds outside Visual Studio (such as builds on a continuous integration server) to use the Prod app.config, but I'd settle for being able to prevent accidental running of a 'Release' build inside Visual Studio. Any suggestions as to if/how this can be achieved are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this just before `</Project>`:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Error Condition=" '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'=='true' And '$(Configuration)'=='Release' "
           Text="JMc is so mad at you you trying to build using the Release configuration from Visual Studio." />
  </Target>
```

Comment: Does the job nicely. Thanks.

Comment: A good alternative using the same condition is to specify DEV values in the app.config and a separate transform for the 'Release' configuration. Then place the 'Condition' within the 'SlowCheetah' property group. The result is that the transform only occurs when building outside VS. When building inside VS you always end up with the DEV app.config file.

Comment: <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' != 'Release' OR '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'=='false' " Label="SlowCheetah">
    <SlowCheetahToolsPath>$([System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath( $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\packages\SlowCheetah.2.5.15\tools\))</SlowCheetahToolsPath>....